# What is the meaning of "You speak no English"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, meaning

I had listened this sentence somewhere, but couldn't recall where. Today I listened the same sentence in the song ["Wanna Know"](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/obietrice/wannaknow.html) by "Obie Trice".

So what is the meaning of the line,

> You speak no English

To me it appears that it means that you do not speak any kind of English.

**Edit**

I am a bit confused with the meaning of the word **any** here. When does the word **no** become **any**?

I know that a sentence like "*I don't care about nobody*" means "*I don't care about anybody*". Does *"no"* become *"any"* only in double-negative type of sentences? But there are sentences like, "*I have no pen*"  mean "I don't have any pen". That is "*no*" is equivalent to "*any*" in usual sentences also.

Another thing, when we say "I have no pen", it means that "I don't have any **type** of pen. So a sentence like "*I have no X*" requires there to be a number of different types of X to exist. But in some sentences like "*I have no milk*", it means "*I don't have any amount of milk*". Could you clear the things up, when is `no=any kind of` and when is `any=any amount of`. Still I can understand when `any=any amount` or `any=any kind of`, from the context, but I can't conceive an objective criteria for this.

Comment: Or it could mean that "I don't understand anything you say."

Comment: You have written in all of the question that `no=any kind of`. I think this is a typing mistake, as it seems like you understand that `no = not any kind of`.

Comment: Oh, and I recommend not learning English from rap songs, as quite often they use massive amounts of slang, and sometimes very offensive words. And I mean **really** offensive (e.g. n**ger). This is what sells rap songs, unfortunately!

Answer (score 1):

*You speak no English* (= “You don’t speak any English”) means, literally, “You have no ability to speak English” rather than “You don’t speak any *kind* or *dialect* of English”.

In the context of the song, however, *You speak no English* is a metaphor (or, arguably, a [*synechdoche*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche)) for “You are ignorant and inarticulate”—specifically, “You have no artistic sensibility”.

> Four niggas in a whip
>   All foes say they ain’t fucking with Trice shit
>   Somebody’s lying, I’m undenying, denying me means that
>   The driver got influence over you on certain things
>   Be distinguished, **just cuz you ain’t feeling his favorite emcee
>
>   Don’t mean you speak no English**
>   Hop out the car, catch the bus
>   At least you be established as the man that you are

Obie Trice invites his listeners to assert their own musical preferences and renounce the ‘influence’ of those who have achieved material success (a *whip* is a Mercedes or similar expensive, high-status car) when they sneer at Obie’s music.

> Just because you’re unimpressed by their favorite artists doesn’t mean that you have no musical taste.

Comment: I am a bit confused with the meaning of the word _any_ here. When does the word `no` become `any`? I know that a sentence like "I don't care about _nobody_" means I don't care about _anybody_. Does no become any only in double-negative type of sentences? But the are sentences like, "I have no pen" which means "I don't have any pen".

Comment: Another thing, when we say "I have no pen", it means that I don't have _any type_ of pen. So a sentence like "I have no X" requires there to be a number of different types of X to exist. But some sentences like "I have no milk", here it means I don't have any _amount_ of milk. Could you clear the things up, when is `no=any kind of` and when is `any=any amount of`. Still I can understand when any=any amount or any=any kind of, but I can't conceive an objective critera for this.

Comment: This is probably more insight than you would ever need into Afro American Vernacular English - [AAVE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English)

Comment: btw, isn't 'all foes say' actually [in reasonably standard E] 'all four are saying' rather than 'all enemies are saying' -  from 'all four is say' ?

Comment: @user31782 *No X* is equivalent to *not any X*; it is not restricted to the specific signification of *no type*. Of course if you have *no pen* you have *no pen of any type* -- as well as *no pen of any color*, *no pen of any size*, *no pen of any brand*: no pen at all.

Comment: @user31782 As you say. Listen to the song and it is clearly "all fo' say", not "all foes say".

Comment: @Tetsujin [Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.winthrop.edu%2Fkosterj%2FENGL507%2Fassignments%2FWolframUrban_AAE.pdf&ei=1qy6VODZFeTlsASvloDoDg&usg=AFQjCNHuitXqp_tDRkAysBEMKHCcPWgpIw&sig2=ttM6YZnm1Gy29gWKZ6dZzw&bvm=bv.83829542,d.eXY)'s another good one.

Comment: My recommendation, user31782, would be to avoid drawing any general principles from Obie's word choices.  "Don't speak no English" is a *very* idiomatic way of talking.  It derives from mocking broken-English, by using the wrong form of the verb "to do" and using a double negative.  These are common mistakes people pick up when trying to learn English by pure immersion (no schooling), so you don't want to accidentally learn bad habits from Obie!